# CKAN preview not working but downloaded CSV is OK

Tags: ckan

I am newbie with CKAN, please could you help me with this error?

```
Could not load view: DataProxy returned an error (Request Error: Backend did not respond after 10 seconds)
```

I don't know why sometimes 1 of 100 tries it show some data. I tried to remove columns, lines but it is not working.

http://sc06.fi.muni.cz/dataset/radar-data/resource/60fdf0fe-0be3-4743-8689-9819fc8448ff

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, this issue happens when using a data proxy to preview the data in the recline view. The file is successfully downloaded because it is saved in the filestore. The first thing to check on your CKAN instance is to check if the [Datapusher](https://docs.ckan.org/projects/datapusher/en/latest/debugging.html) is working and the dataset is successfully uploaded in the [datastore](https://docs.ckan.org/en/latest/maintaining/datastore.html#test-the-set-up).

Answer (score 1):

I suffered a lot to solve this same problem, I want to help you, if you still need:

In
`docker_ckan_home/_data/venv/src/ckan/ckanext/reclineview/theme/public/recline_view.js`,
increase variable value `recline.Backend.DataProxy.timeout = 100000;`

In my case I increase to 100000.